# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Veriler'

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror

I have unexpected keywords argument error in the below codes. Where is my missing point or mistake?

```py
Veriler = pd.DataFrame(Veriler = Veriler_modeled, columns = selected_columns)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Veriler'
```

Comment: Is `Veriler = Veriler_modeled` intended to assign the data / columns of the dataframe? You're not calling DataFrame in a valid way. Basic signature is `DataFrame(columns=blah, data=blah)`  See the Pandas API docs for the full story

Comment: I think that what happened is that the initialization method got a keyword labelled "Veriler" that was unexpected. Are you unfamiliar with what "keyword argument" means? https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-are-keyword-arguments-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `data` instead of `Veriler` in parameters